# Передача в on_select_changed функцию flet

Tags: python, flet

Прошу помочь в решении проблемы.
Мне нужно передать,к примеру, в on_select_changed
объекта DataRow функцию с переменными, т.е. мне нужно получить состояние через handler и присвоить его переменной.

Имеется DataTable :

```
self.t = ft.DataTable( 
                columns=[
                    ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("")),
                    ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Поле 1")),
                    ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Поле 2")),
                    ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Поле 3"))
                    
                                                    
                ],expand=1, 
                
            )
        for i in range(len(tablearr)):
            
            self.t.rows = self.t.rows + [
                    ft.DataRow(
                        cells=[
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Checkbox()),
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(tablearr[i][0])),
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(tablearr[i][4])),
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(tablearr[i][1]))                            
                            
                        ],on_select_changed=func1(self.arr)
                    ),]
```

При возникновении события on_select_changed должна срабатывать функция func1:

```
def func1(self,spl)
    self.control.cells[0].content.value = True
    spl = spl + str(self.control.cells[1].content.value)
    page.update()
```

Я так понимаю, чт в функцию кроме заполняемой переменной нужно передать handler. Как его передать?

Comment: Добрый день! Пробовал lambda. Сейчас опишу пример с DataTable.

Comment: @СергейКох, добавил пример.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается очень просто. Создал статическую переменную и присваиваю ей значение в функции func1